# How to send Dictionary as parameter to the Get Request Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, iphone, swift4

i  have to call  GET API like

required :

```
http://ctesterst.net/api/Customers/homeData?lat=12.456&lng=76.786&current_app_version=123&current_device=%7B%22Test%22%3A%22123%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22something%22%2C%22tested%22%3Atrue%7D&access_token=Km3R2AbU0yzAcVkp9BCxmCmaoC5k20fBiQxfLhIBIAolwJGgYw5w5E8X0NZzlDh8
```

like that i have to call.

input parameters  how to add ??

i am doing like this :

my json string is : request model

```
 struct RequestData: Codable {
                struct Devices: Codable {
                    let test: String
                    let name: String
                    let tested:Bool
                }
                let   current_device: Devices

            }
```

and my url is :

```
urlAppend = val + "&lat=\(lati)" + "&lng=\(long)" + "&current_app_version=\(appVersion)" + "&current_device=\(jsonString)"
```

its getting crash .. please  give me solution .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use URLComponents for this, URLComponents is defined in Foundation.

```
        var components = URLComponents()

        components.scheme = "http"
        components.host = "ctesterst.net"
        components.path = "/api/Customers/homeData"

        let queryItemLat = URLQueryItem(name: "lat", value: "12.456")
        let queryItemLong = URLQueryItem(name: "lng", value: "76.786")
        let queryItemAppVersion = URLQueryItem(name: "current_app_version", value: "123")
        let queryItemDevice = URLQueryItem(name: "current_device", value: "something")
        let queryItemToken = URLQueryItem(name: "access_token", value: "Km3R2AbU0yzAcVkp9BCxmCmaoC5k20fBiQxfLhIBIAolwJGgYw5w5E8X0NZzlDh8")

        components.queryItems = [queryItemLat, queryItemLong,queryItemAppVersion,queryItemDevice,queryItemToken]
        print(components.url)
```

Comment: @Dara tx for replay .. but even i user ur answer also .. it  giving same output .

Comment: Is it crashing? Have you try calling url which is prepared in components.url ?

Comment: not crashing ...  url fine. the problem with my input -- encoding issue . i taken ur answer as a reference ...  and its worked .

Comment: ur answer solved my 80 % issue for my input issue  .. thanks alot .

Comment: Happy to help you